# Etiqueta iframe

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Cuento con una duda sobre la etiqueta iframe en html puesto que tengo esta etiqueta en un modal y siempre que cargo la pagina el video que tiene esta etiqueta empieza a reproducir sin que haya siquiera abierto este modal, alguna idea sobre este evento ?  alguna forma de hacer que solo se reproduzca cuando le de en el btn del play o solo cuando se abra el modal ?

```
<div id="modal{{$filesVideo->id}}" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content center-align">
    <iframe class="responsive-video" src="{{'../images/video/'.$filesVideo->name}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Podrías colocar el código del modal y el iframe? Puedes hacer que el iframe se genere con javascript como hijo del modal al llamarlo.

Answer (score 0):

No es muy dificil buscar en Google, de [esta respuesta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22748681/how-to-prevent-autoplay-in-iframe-html)

Debes usar la etiqueta `<video>` , envés de `<iframe>` para prevenir el autoplay.

```
<video width="200" height="200" controls>

<source src="{{'../images/video/'.$filesVideo->name}}" type="video/mp4">

</video>
```